# How to show or hide UIVIew

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uistoryboard

I'm making an app.

I will offer both simple mode and detail mode.

In Detail mode, I have to show UIView.

However, this UIView contains various objects such as buttons and labels.

So It is hard to generate by code. (because it's constraints is really complex.)

So I want to make it in the storyboard beforehand.

And then, I want to show this UIVIew in the main view when only detail mode.

It is possible??

**One thing to keep in mind is that I need to keep the constraints I created in the storyboard.

Comment: Can you share design/wire frame, what exactly you want to hide/show?

Comment: do `view.isHidden = true/false` in necessary conditions

Comment: @SahebRoy oh my god. Thank you guy!!! It was solved very simply.

Comment: ;) glad it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use a height constraint to that view and then use `yourViewHeightContstraintVar.constant = 0` ? or if you want to keep the space that view have then use `yourView.isHidden = true`. Hope it helps